Show that $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n[\cos (x+k)]^d\to (d-1)!!/d!! \mbox{ for $d$ is even } $
Let $((-\pi,\pi], \mathcal{B}((-\pi,\pi]), m)$ be a measure space with Lebesgue measure $m$. Show that for $m$-a.e. all $x\in (-\pi, \pi]$ that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n[\cos (x+k)]^d\to (d-1)!!/d!! \mbox{ for $d$ is even }
$$
otherwise it is $0$, as $n\to \infty$.

I try to apply strong law of large number. However, I am not sure how to define the related random variables?
It seems that if we let $a_k:=[\cos (x+k)]^d$, then by strong law of large number
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\to \int_{-\pi}^\pi ?
$$

By the Equidistribution Theorem, we have $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\cos(x+k)]^d \to \int_{0}^{1} [\cos(x+2\pi t)]^d , \mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{1} [\cos(2\pi t)]^d , \mathrm{d}t$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now you can conclude by evaluating the last integral.
